# Use AngularFire Auth Guard redirectUnauthorizedTo and then redirect to original URL

Tags: angular, angularfire

I'm currently using `redirectUnauthorizedTo(['login'])` guard utility from `@angular/fire/auth-guard`, but now I want to redirect users to the original route they were trying to access after a successful login. It seems that it's not possible to access the original route from the `Router` module inside the `LoginComponent`, so I wanted to know if it's possible to use this same Guard to include the original route in the router object that arrives at my `LoginComponent`.

Comment: Can you answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74575931/how-to-use-angularfire-redirectunauthorizedto-to-redirect-unauthorized-users-b

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesn't make this very clear, but the `AuthPipeGenerator` takes two arguments: the route snapshot and the route state. This lets you pass the original URL path to the sign-in page (note that it will be added to the `params` object rather than the `queryParams` object, so make sure that you choose params that don't clash with anything you are already using in the sign-in page).

```js
const redirectFromDashboard = (_: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
  return redirectUnauthorizedTo(['/sign-in', { path: state.url }]);
};

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  data: { authGuardPipe: redirectFromDashboard },
  ...
}]
```